# Range function gives an extra output in my template

Tags: go, hugo

I am following [this](https://davidtranscend.com/blog/how-to-create-an-archives-page-with-hugo/) link to figure out how to create an archives page. I am using the [hugo-xmin](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin) theme with slight modifications.

As far as I understand, `range` goes through the pages and should print them out. But, I am getting an additional `0001` also. I don't understand why. I'm still a beginner to Hugo and Go.

My **output** (circled portion in red not what I want)

[image]

My `archives.html`

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}

<div class="article-meta">
<h1><span class="title">{{ .Title | markdownify }}</span></h1>
{{ with .Params.author }}<h2 class="author">{{ . }}</h2>{{ end }}
{{ if (gt .Params.date 0) }}<h2 class="date">{{ .Date.Format "2006/01/02" }}</h2>{{ end     }}
</div>



<main class="content" role="main">
    <div class="inner">
{{ range (.Site.RegularPages.GroupByDate "2006") }}
<h3>{{ .Key }}</h3>
<ul>
  {{ range (where .Pages "Type" "post") }}
  <li>
    <span class="date">{{ .Date.Format "2006/01/02" }}</span>
    <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
  </li>
  {{ end }}
</ul>
{{ end }}
</div>
</main>


{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

My `archives.md`

```
---
title: "Archives"
layout: "archives"
draft: false
---

This is archives
```

My directory structure

```
.
├── archetypes
│   └── default.md
├── config.toml
├── content
│   ├── about.md
│   ├── archives.md
│   ├── _index.md
│   ├── post
│   │   ├── first_post.md
│   │   ├── sample_code.md
│   │   └── test_math.md
│   └── reading.md
├── data
├── layouts
├── static
└── themes
    └── mytheme
        ├── archetypes
        │   └── default.md
        ├── layouts
        │   ├── 404.html
        │   ├── archives.html
        │   ├── _default
        │   │   ├── archives.html
        │   │   ├── list.html
        │   │   ├── single.html
        │   │   └── terms.html
        │   ├── index.html
        │   └── partials
        │       ├── foot_custom.html
        │       ├── footer.html
        │       ├── head_custom.html
        │       └── header.html
        ├── LICENSE.md
        ├── static
        │   ├── css
        │   │   ├── fonts.css
        │   │   └── style.css
        │   └── js
        └── theme.toml

15 directories, 25 files
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `archives.html` to the following, with some help from [hugo-lithium](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/blob/master/layouts/_default/list.html). It works for my use case now. But I still don't understand why the **0001** came up in the first place. So I will not be marking my answer as correct for now.

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}

<div class="article-meta">
<h1><span class="title">{{ .Title | markdownify }}</span></h1>
{{ with .Params.author }}<h2 class="author">{{ . }}</h2>{{ end }}
{{ if (gt .Params.date 0) }}<h2 class="date">{{ .Date.Format "2006/01/02" }}</h2>{{ end     }}
</div>


{{ range (where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "!=" "").GroupByDate "2006" }}
  <h2>{{ .Key }}</h2>
  <ul>
  {{ range .Pages }}
  <li>
    <span class="date">{{ .Date.Format "2006/02/02" }}</span>
    <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
  </li>
  {{ end }}
  </ul>
{{ end }}



{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```